# Crystal report -- invalid log on parameter error

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a crystal report which was working fine on my local machine but when I moved it to my server it's giving me a "Incorrect Log on parameters".

Code is below. It's called from a .net application

Dim CR As New ReportDocument

```
    Dim str As String = Application.StartupPath
    If PrintDialog1.ShowDialog() <> Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then Exit Sub
    CR.Load(Application.StartupPath & "\CR Reports\BookPickByConsignee.rpt")
    CR.SetParameterValue("param_picknumber", Me.txtpickNumber.Text.Trim())
    CR.DataSourceConnections.Item(0).SetConnection(Configuration.ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings("DatabaseServer").ToString(), Configuration.ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings("DatabaseName").ToString(), Configuration.ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings("UserName").ToString(), Configuration.ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings("Password").ToString())
    'CR.DataSourceConnections.Item(0).SetLogon("sa", "pwd")
    '            CR.SetDatabaseLogon("sa", "pwd")

    CR.PrintOptions.PrinterName = PrintDialog1.PrinterSettings.PrinterName

    CR.PrintToPrinter(Me.txtCopies.Text, True, 1, 100)
    CR.Close()
```

Comment: Well, I have to ask -- is the configuration file on your server pointing to the right database?  Have you verified this?

Comment: @Amit, please fix the formatting of your code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code to apply certain connection details for a report at run time.
Sorry, code in c#.
Please use that method just after loading report rpt file, instead of `CR.DataSourceConnections.Item(0).SetConnection` and pass required connection details to method, it will work.

```
    public static void CrystalReportLogOn(ReportDocument reportParameters,
                                          string serverName,
                                          string databaseName,
                                          string userName,
                                          string password)
    {
        TableLogOnInfo logOnInfo;
        ReportDocument subRd;
        Sections sects;
        ReportObjects ros;
        SubreportObject sro;

        if (reportParameters == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("reportParameters");
        }

        try
        {
            foreach (CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.Table t in reportParameters.Database.Tables)
            {
                logOnInfo = t.LogOnInfo;
                logOnInfo.ReportName = reportParameters.Name;
                logOnInfo.ConnectionInfo.ServerName = serverName;
                logOnInfo.ConnectionInfo.DatabaseName = databaseName;
                logOnInfo.ConnectionInfo.UserID = userName;
                logOnInfo.ConnectionInfo.Password = password;
                logOnInfo.TableName = t.Name;
                t.ApplyLogOnInfo(logOnInfo);
                t.Location = t.Name;
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            throw;
        }

        sects = reportParameters.ReportDefinition.Sections;
        foreach (Section sect in sects)
        {
            ros = sect.ReportObjects;
            foreach (ReportObject ro in ros)
            {
                if (ro.Kind == ReportObjectKind.SubreportObject)
                {
                    sro = (SubreportObject)ro;
                    subRd = sro.OpenSubreport(sro.SubreportName);
                    try
                    {
                        foreach (CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.Table t in subRd.Database.Tables)
                        {
                            logOnInfo = t.LogOnInfo;
                            logOnInfo.ReportName = reportParameters.Name;
                            logOnInfo.ConnectionInfo.ServerName = serverName;
                            logOnInfo.ConnectionInfo.DatabaseName = databaseName;
                            logOnInfo.ConnectionInfo.UserID = userName;
                            logOnInfo.ConnectionInfo.Password = password;
                            logOnInfo.TableName = t.Name;
                            t.ApplyLogOnInfo(logOnInfo);
                        }
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                        throw;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```